# Print only 3rd or more time occuring string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I run below grep command in a directory

```
zgrep 'IMPRESSION REQ. SERVER HEADERS' * | zgrep -o -P "s=.{31}"
```

and the output is like below

> s=9395cb8e3284ef8a91ba6520780a9
>
> s=9395cb8e3284ef8a91ba6520780a9
>
> s=a55aa6bc73d414f32d8fc343f83fc
>
> s=a55aa6bc73d414f32d8fc343f83fc
>
> s=71922d4280b7cf1d7adcb51d8d0d2
>
> s=71922d4280b7cf1d7adcb51d8d0d2
>
> s=71922d4280b7cf1d7adcb51d8d0d2
>
> s=1b13dcadb9c807ab4cb985b893fd7

Is there a single command in unix with the help of which I can print only those distinct lines which are occuring 3 and more than 3 times

so here my output should be only `s=71922d4280b7cf1d7adcb51d8d0d2` as this is occuring 3 times, I know its possible by writing a small shell script but I am looking if there is a way to do it via a single command

Comment: `awk '++a[$0]==3'` ?

Comment: @123: Post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple one with perl - you can also probably include some other bits of your pipe into it.

```
perl -ne 'print if ++$seen{$_} >= 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
sort your_file | uniq -c | awk '$1>2 {print $2}'
```

- `sort` sorts the file
- `uniq -c` is simply a "group by", the result will be two columns

> ```
> 1 s=1b13dcadb9c807ab4cb985b893fd7
> 3 s=71922d4280b7cf1d7adcb51d8d0d2
> 2 s=9395cb8e3284ef8a91ba6520780a9
> 2 s=a55aa6bc73d414f32d8fc343f83fc
> ```

And finally using `awk` script we print the second column if the count greater than 2.

Comment: This works well when i have copied the output of command 

zgrep 'IMPRESSION REQ. SERVER HEADERS' * | zgrep -o -P "s=.{31}" in a file and i run command                                                                  sort your_file | uniq -c | awk '$1>2 {print $2}' on that particular file, but its giving me strange output when i run it as a single command zgrep 'IMPRESSION REQ. SERVER HEADERS' * | zgrep -o -P "s=.{31}" | sort | tee uniq -c | awk '$1>2 {print $2}'